# Webhooks won't load

Tags: node.js, pipedrive-api

In this webpage : https://webhooks-manager.pipedrive.com/web/#/

I've got an infinite loading, looking at console :

```
OPTIONS #LINK# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED fetch-browser.js:445

XHR failed loading: GET "#LINK#". fetch-browser.js:445

app:error initial data load failed: TypeError: Network request failed +0ms Browser.js:445

OXHR failed loading: GET #LINK#. fetch-browser.js:445

OPTIONS #LINK# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED fetch-browser.js:445
```

LINK : https://app.pipedrive.in/api/v1/users/self/?session_token=a_token&strict_mode=true&_=a_number

If the error is only for me I would like to get some help.. If I'm not alone how to report at dev ?

ps : can't post more than two links.. that's why I've created LINK

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Pipedrive support rep here.

The editor app won't load unless opened in its intended context, https://app.pipedrive.com/webhooks. 
Should you wish to work on your webhooks without the GUI, please refer to the following section of Pipedrive's API documentation:
https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#!/Webhooks

I hope this helps.